# Change of baseUrl for PHPUnit in Laravel 5.4

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.4

It seems that before Laravel 5.4 we could change the URL for testing by coding like this:

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://someurl.com';
```

But now it is not working and some suggest we have to use this method

```
function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    config(['app.url' => 'http://yourcustomeaddress.loc']);
}
```

Would anybody help me and tell Where I should put this method?

Answer (score 4):

You may put it in `tests/TestCase.php` (Laravel 5.4 example):

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        config(['app.url' => 'http://yourcustomeaddress.loc']);
    }

    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

Or you may add it in specific test:

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        config(['app.url' => 'http://yourcustomeaddress.loc']);
    }
// your test functions
}
```