# get request in Laravel phpunit test searches for different url

Tags: laravel, get, phpunit

I'm trying to create a simple phpunit test for a Note model in my Laravel app. I simply want to test that a get request to a specific note instance will display some of that note's properties.

I have a Note model, factory, controller and route.

**Model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function path()
    {
        return "/notes/{$this->id}";
    }
}
```

**Factory**

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Note::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'body' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/notes/{note}', 'NotesController@show');
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Note;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class NotesController extends Controller
{
      public function show(Note $note)
      {
         return view('notes.show', compact('note'));
      }
}
```

**Test**

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class NotesTest extends TestCase
{

    use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_view_a_note()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $note = factory('App\Note')->create();
        // dd($note->path());

        $this->get($note->path())
            ->assertSee($note->title)
            ->assertSee($note->body);
    }
}
```

When I run the `a_user_can_view_a_note` test, I get this error:

> 1) Tests\Feature\NotesTest::a_user_can_view_a_note
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: GET
>   http://shepherding.test/1

Instead of looking for `http://shepherding.test/notes/1`, it's looking for `http://shepherding.test/1`.

---

PS: `dd($note->path());` gives `"/notes/1".`

I can replace `$this->get($note->path())` with this:

```
$this->get('/notes/' . $note->id);
```

or even replace it this hard-coded value:

```
$this->get('/notes/1');
```

But the test keeps trying to get `http://shepherding.test/1`.

I can't figure out why the `/notes/` is being stripped out of the get request.

I have other tests for index and store that all work fine. Just this one is showing this behavior.

Comment: can you comment out all other routes in the app and see if the test passes? Maybe you have a redirection in some other route?

Comment: Thanks - just tried that - commented out all routes except for the one shown in my question. But the problem persists. I'll comb through the code and make sure there are no redirects anywhere else, outside the routes, though.

Comment: I couldn't find any redirect anywhere in the code. So, I decided to just work around the test and verify that the model/controller/routes actually do all work. Sure enough, they do. It seems it's only the test itself which somehow keeps stripping /notes/ out of the get request, and producing a fail. Maybe there's something about PHPUnit tests that causes this that I'm blissfully ignorant of?

Comment: Using a named route also works...

Comment: When you comment out all other routes, and run `php artisan route:list`, do you see only that `/notes/{note}` route?

Comment: @Amade - Most of the routes go away, but not all of them. There are still routes for a user model.  Also there are routes for some other service providers (Telescope, which is currently disabled, as well as debugbar). There are also still a couple of resource routes where the URI is prefixed with api/ that still remain.

Comment: forgot to ask about it before - does it work as expected, when you open the url directly in the browser?

Comment: @Amade Yes, it does. Basically everything is working, except for the test itself. And I've since discovered that if I use a named route, even the test works. As soon as I specify the route as shown above (`$this->get('/notes/' . $note->id);` or `$this->get('/notes/1');`) - the `/notes/` gets stripped from the request.

Comment: What do you get when you `dd()` the named route?

Comment: Here's the route, named 'shownote': `Route::get('/notes/{note}', 'NotesController@show')->name('shownote');`          `dd(route('shownote', $note->id));` gives `http://shepherding.test/notes/1`.          `dd('/notes/' . $note->id);` gives `/notes/1`.             And `dd($note->path());` gives `/notes/1`.    Sorry about the formatting, I can't seem to get the double space after a line to create a new line.

Comment: ok, so we know now that when you pass the full path to `$this->get()` the test works. I think you might be able to find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22967227/4171578

Comment: That was it. Thank you.  For reference, this thread fills in some other information I didn't have about how to make the change to the TestCase.php file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381501/change-of-baseurl-for-phpunit-in-laravel-5-4.  If anyone has an answer, I'd be curious do know why the tests don't automatically use APP_URL from the .env file?